# How i create a model with a sub model in flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, model, runtime-error

i was try to create a model with a sub model inside, but when try do get the data or put the data at this sub model make a error:

the models:

```
class BannerTextFormat {
  FontWeight ?bold;
  double ?size;
  Color ?color;

  BannerTextFormat({this.bold, this.size, this.color});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'bold': bold,
    'size': size,
    'color': color,
  };

  BannerTextFormat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) :
        bold = json['bold'],
        size = json['size'],
        color = json['color']
  ;

}

class ContaBanner {
  String ?texto;
  String ?imageBackground;
  Color ?colorBackground;
  BannerTextFormat ?textFormat;

  ContaBanner({this.texto, this.imageBackground, this.colorBackground, this.textFormat});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'texto': texto,
    'imageBackground': imageBackground,
    'colorBackground': colorBackground,
    'textformat': BannerTextFormat.fromJson(textFormat as Map<String, dynamic>)
  };

}
```

and the message error: null check operator on null value, at this lines above, this error shows when i execute the app, not when i compile, sorry my English

```
ContaBanner contaBanner = ContaBanner();
contaBanner.textFormat?.size = 30; \\error here
```

Comment: try to print your value data and runtimeType data before put or get model

Answer (score 0):

Color ?colorBackground;
BannerTextFormat ?textFormat;

Java code

int color;
String textFormat;

Comment: BannerTextFormat  ists another model

Answer (score 0):

the corrcect way to creat a class model at this way:

```
class BannerTextFormat {
  FontWeight ?bold;
  double ?size;
  Color ?color;

  BannerTextFormat({this.bold, this.size, this.color});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'bold': bold,
    'size': size,
    'color': color,
  };

  BannerTextFormat.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) :
        bold = json['bold'],
        size = json['size'],
        color = json['color']
  ;

}

class ContaBanner {
  String ?texto;
  String ?imageBackground;
  Color ?colorBackground;
  BannerTextFormat ?textFormat;

  ContaBanner({this.texto, this.imageBackground, this.colorBackground, this.textFormat});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['texto'] = texto;
    data['imageBackground'] = imageBackground;
    data['colorBackground'] = colorBackground;
    if (textFormat != null) {
      data['textFormat'] = textFormat!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }

  ContaBanner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) :
    texto = json['texto'],
    imageBackground = json['imageBackground'],
    colorBackground = json['colorBackground'],
    textFormat = BannerTextFormat.fromJson(json['textFormat']);

}
```

works perfectly